# Roles with Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am currently working on a project for a client. I'm trying to assign roles to users at the time they sign up for an account.

```
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({message:'',messageClass:'hidden'});
    var that = this;
    var first_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.first_name).value.trim();
    var last_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.last_name).value.trim();
    var email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value.trim();
    var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value.trim();
    var type = 'fan';
    var user = {email:email,password:password,profile:{fullname:(first_name + last_name).toLowerCase(),firsname:first_name,lastname:last_name,avatar:'http://placehold.it/150x150',friends:[],type:type}};
    Accounts.createUser(user,function(e){
        if (e) {
            Materialize.toast(e.reason, 5000);
        } else {
            FlowRouter.go('/dashboard');
        }
    })
}
```

Above is my handle submit event for the signup form. Below is the hook that I added to assign the role to the user after the user is inserted.

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
if (doc.profile.type === "fan") {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Fan])
}
```

});

What I'm finding is that the user gets created but instead of being redirected to the dashboard, the user remains on the signup page and receives an error in the toaster message stating internal server error. When I go into the console to find the user that was created, the profile type is assigned but the user is missing their email address.

This is the error I'm getting in my terminal window:

> Exception while invoking method 'createUser' ReferenceError: ROLES is
>   not defined I20160402-16:04:42.482(-4)?     at Object.
>   (both/collection_hooks/hooks.jsx:3:35) I20160402-16:04:42.482(-4)?
>   at packages/matb33_collection-hooks/insert.js:35:1
>   I20160402-16:04:42.482(-4)?     at Array.forEach
>   (packages/es5-shim/.npm/package/node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js:417:1)
>   I20160402-16:04:42.483(-4)?     at Function.*.each.*.forEach
>   (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1) I20160402-16:04:42.483(-4)? 
>   at after (packages/matb33_collection-hooks/insert.js:34:1)
>   I20160402-16:04:42.483(-4)?     at
>   Object.CollectionHooks.defineAdvice.self
>   (packages/matb33_collection-hooks/insert.js:49:1)
>   I20160402-16:04:42.485(-4)?     at Object.collection.(anonymous
>   function) [as insert]
>   (packages/matb33_collection-hooks/collection-hooks.js:117:1)
>   I20160402-16:04:42.485(-4)?     at [object
>   Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert]
>   (packages/mongo/collection.js:590:1) I20160402-16:04:42.485(-4)?
>   at AccountsServer.Ap.insertUserDoc (accounts_server.js:1248:25)
>   I20160402-16:04:42.486(-4)?     at createUser
>   (password_server.js:980:25)

Does anyone have any idea what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ROLES` isn't defined in the context of your hook. It's either not a global or you're using Meteor 1.3 and you haven't exported it from the file you've defined it in and imported it into the file where you defined your hook.

Comment: That makes sense. That's where I seem to be stuck though is making it global. I'm using Meteor 1.2.1

Comment: Define it without a `var` - just `ROLES = { }` in a file under `/lib`

Comment: This does get rid of the internal server error and the user gets created but the role array returns empty when I fetch the user in the console.

Comment: Are you publishing the user's `roles` key from the server or is it part of the `profile` key?

Comment: It's just attached to the user. The user type is a part of the profile but roles is in a separate field on the user object.

Comment: I suppose it's also worth noting that I haven't removed auto publish and insecure yet.

Comment: The way I'm used to modifying the user object on create is with a `before.insert` hook that modifies the user object and returns it.

Comment: I see. So basically something like: Meteor.users.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
if (doc.profile.type === "fan") {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Fan])
}
return user;
});

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work unless `Roles.addUsersToRoles()` modifies `doc` which contains the `user` object in that function. You'd want to return `doc`, not `user` which is undefined.